# pandas pivot table arrangement

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to create a pivot table and use to multiple `aggfuncs`; specifically `np.mean` and `np.std`. The normal behavior of `pandas.pivot_tables` would be to place the `aggfuncs` on top hierarchically. If you only had one column in `value` this wouldn't matter, but I have 7. This makes reading the table a little bit tedious. I would like to be able to place the values on top of the hierarchy so that within each `value` there is a mean and std column. Is there a way that this can be done or am I sol?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** Here is a small excerpt of the data.

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4     Col5     Col6   Col7    Col8   Col9    
A       A        0      4247     5684     2068   393    237    16286
A       A        0        0      2366     4159   3155   696    341     
A       B        18198    0        1114   1871   5392   1954   755  
A       B        17829    0      2695     2366   3768   1289   445
A       C        18352    0      3545     7508   5099   2071   1239
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
                  Col 3        Col 4        Col 5        Col 6        Col 7  ...
Col 1  Col 2   Mean   Std   Mean    Std   Mean   Std   Mean   Std   Mean   Std  ...
A      A       0      0     2123.5 2173.5 ...
       B       ...
       C       ...
```

I'm not going to run through all the calcs right now but I think that gets the point across as this is a formatting question.

Comment: What you could do is use groupby function. This returning a dictionary. Then use a custom print method with the dictionary. You can .mean() and .std() method.   Please show data and desired layout.

Comment: @merlin I added some of the data and desired layout

Comment: @Merlin Just got back to review it. That is it indeed. Should have read all the way through the groupby docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change your row headings from "Col 1" >> "Col1"

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_clipboard()

df

Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4     Col5     Col6   Col7    Col8   Col9    
A       A        0      4247     5684     2068   393    237    16286
A       A        0        0      2366     4159   3155   696    341     
A       B        18198    0        1114   1871   5392   1954   755  
A       B        17829    0      2695     2366   3768   1289   445
A       C        18352    0      3545     7508   5099   2071   1239 




  In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: np.round(df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).agg(['mean', 'std']),4)
Out[10]:
              Col3              Col4               Col5               Col6  \
              mean       std    mean        std    mean        std    mean
Col1 Col2
A    A         0.0    0.0000  2123.5  3003.0825  4025.0  2346.1803  3113.5
     B     18013.5  260.9224     0.0     0.0000  1904.5  1117.9358  2118.5
     C     18352.0       NaN     0.0        NaN  3545.0        NaN  7508.0

                      Col7               Col8             Col9
                 std  mean        std    mean      std    mean         std
Col1 Col2
A    A     1478.5603  1774  1953.0289   466.5  324.562  8313.5  11274.8176
     B      350.0179  4580  1148.3414  1621.5  470.226   600.0    219.2031
     C           NaN  5099        NaN  2071.0      NaN  1239.0         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved using a combo of .describe() (which has both mean and std stats) and .pivot. Say you have a DF that looks like this:

```
print(df)

        City          Country                   lon
0       Dubai         United Arab Emirates   55.307484
254     Buenos Aires  Argentina             -58.381592
1002    Rosario       Argentina             -60.666500
1162    Punta Arenas  Chile                 -70.916473
1178    San Miguel    Argentina             -65.217590
```

and you want to get the statistics on the 'lon' column for each country. Use .describe to get the statistics:

```
stats = df.groupby('Country').describe()
#reset index so that you can specify the columns later
stats.reset_index(level = [0,1], inplace = True)
stats.head()
    Country level_1 lon
0   Albania count   1.0000
1   Albania mean    19.8318
2   Albania std     NaN
3   Albania min     19.8318
4   Albania 25%     19.8318
```

Then do a pivot table based on your stats table. Since the result will be multi-indexed, you need to specify tuple columns to access the mean and std columns:

```
stats.pivot('Country', 'level_1')[[('lon', 'mean'), ('lon', 'std')]]
```

the result will be something like:

```
    lon
level_1 mean    std
Country     
Albania 19.831800   NaN
Algeria 2.744837    3.323134
Angola  13.234444   NaN
Argentina   -63.806806  4.101027
```

Let me know if this helps--good luck.

Comment: Im having some trouble implementing this with my format. When the script gets to `stats.pivot`. In my case stats.head() doesnt have a label for the stats descriptor column, its just blank. So im not sure how to call it in the `columns=` key for stats.pivot(index, columns).

Comment: This is what the 'reset_index' line is for. Basically, when you run the .describe() function, it sets the stats column as an index. So if you did, like in my example, .reset_index(level = [0,1], inplace = True), it might not work if you have more/less indicies than my original DF. I had two indicies (the Country and the stats column), hence the two elements in the elvels arg. So try playing around with the numbers you put into the level argument.

Comment: I tried implementing this with the stats.reset_index function but now im getting a ValueError: Length Mismatch.The code i am trying is `stats.pivot(['Col 1', 'Col 2'], 'level_2')[column_tuples]` column_tuples is a list of the (col name, mean), (col name, std) tuples

Comment: I have been able to get the table to the format that i want by creating a multiindex from product using the list of data cols as the first index and a list of the two summary stats I want as the second. I make a pivot table from the original data using col 1 and col 2 as index, then cols 3 - 9 as values, and mean and std as aggfunc. I then apply the multiindex to this table with `reindex_axis`. The result is the properly formatted table but the data is missing.